# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Android Emulator Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, express, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I'm new to cordova and create a project in visual studio 2015 for test send and receiving data in JSON format, I run the Codes below in Android Emulator in Visual studio 2015 and i expect the Node.js server shows email and password, but i get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

I put this code in the onDeviceReady block in index.js:

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", { email: "test@test.com", password: "123456" },
    function (data, status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
```

and the meta tag in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://127.0.0.1:3000/">
```

Node.js server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {  
    var email = req.body.email;
    var pass = req.body.password;
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    console.log(email + ", " + pass);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

What is the problem?

**Update:**
I run the project in my nexus device and the problem is solved! 
but some points should be considered:
1. i change IP address to my real IP of server!
2. when i use domain instead of IP address the `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error is shown!

my questions:
1. `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error still remains in android emulator. why?
2. use domain lead to `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. why?

Comment: Did you use `socket.io` in your Node.js server file?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT No, i did not.

Answer (score 0):

In CMD, type "ipconfig" and find the IP device below: "vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port), Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch".

Finally, instead of 127.0.0.1, use IP of the internal ethernet port of the Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch.